# Ionic 3 RxJS fires c.clear() continuously

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 with RxJS module. The problem is that the console is being cleared continuously. Upon preserving the console log and clicking the link that directs to the code that executes it, it came from RxJS. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this by removing unnecessary extensions in Chrome. The issue is not related to RxJS or Ionic 3.